# Laravel token authentication

Tags: laravel, api, authentication

I have a Laravel API (actually a Lumen API) serving a VueJS front-end. The Vue app allows users to login to Google. The Google token is then sent back to the Lumen API, which verifies the token with Google, then verifies that the email address is a valid user. Then it generates a token, stores that in the DB with the user and returns the user object.

I'm not using Passport or jwt-auth or anything like that. So now, how do I go about using the default Auth middleware to verify the token header that the (now logged in) user will be returning with every request? (i.e. is the token in the DB and is it expired?). And is there a way to do this more efficiently, so Laravel caches the valid tokens and doesn't have to hit the DB for every request?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Authentication Middleware`. Pass with your request an `api_token`. A more detailed answer can be found [here](https://gistlog.co/JacobBennett/090369fbab0b31130b51).

Add a `api_token` column to your `User` table.

```
$table->string('api_token', 60)->unique();
```

Have an authentication middleware as such:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
class Authenticate
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {

            if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            } else {
                return redirect()->guest('auth/login');
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

And use [Route Group](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#route-groups)

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {

    Route::resource('api/v1/foo/bar', 'API\FooBarController');

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But how do I get past the `Auth::guard($guard)->guest()` check in the middleware? I am storing the token (with an expiry date) in the database.

Comment: In your route group, the syntax is `'middleware' => 'auth:guardName'`